# Python: Numpy standard deviation error

Tags: python, numpy

This is a simple test

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([-1,0,1])
print data.std()

>> 0.816496580928
```

I don't understand how this result been generated? Obviously:

```
( (1^0.5 + 1^0.5 + 0^0.5)/(3-1) )^0.5 = 1
```

and in matlab it gives me `std([-1,0,1]) = 1`. Could you help me get understand how `numpy.std()` works?

Comment: Dividing by N-1 gives the sample variance, but NumPy computes the population variance.

Comment: Giving this an upvote because the difference between population and sample standard deviation is seldom paid attention to until results fail to match - picking one, and knowing why you're using it, will both help prevent this problem and also force you to usefully think about your problem a bit more.  (All said from unpleasant experience.).

Answer (score 27):

The crux of this problem is that you need to divide by `N` (3), not `N-1` (2). As Iarsmans pointed out, numpy will use the population variance, not the sample variance.

So the real answer is `sqrt(2/3)` which is exactly that: `0.8164965...`

If you happen to be trying to deliberately use a different value (than the default of 0) for the degrees of freedom, use the keyword argument `ddof`with a positive value other than 0:

```
np.std(data, ddof=1)
```

... but doing so *here* would reintroduce your original problem as numpy will divide by `N - ddof`.

Comment: sorry, the 2 is just typo. I think the np.std() is just universal std. If it is a sample std, it should be N-1. Is there a function for sample std?

Comment: @MacSanhe Ah, then that makes more sense how you could make that mistake!

Comment: @MacSanhe Edited with details to address your concern.

Comment: This appears to be incorrect. The numpy docs indicate it uses an uncorrected sample standard deviation by default, with ddof=0. ddof=1 will enable population variance (makes it less biased towards the sample mean). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let me check to see if things have changed since I wrote this answer.

Comment: Ah, the confusion is the addendum where I show how you can change the degrees of freedom if desired. Coming back to this, I'm not confident it is super relevant. Regardless, I'll clear up the formatting to highlight that the problem was the user was dividing by `N-1` instead of `N`. Using `N` and then using `ddof=1` would in fact, reintroduce the original problem!

Answer (score 6):

It is worth reading the help page for the function/method before suggesting it is incorrect. The method does exactly what the doc-string says it should be doing, divides by 3, because **By default `ddof`is zero.**:

```
In [3]: numpy.std?

String form: <function std at 0x104222398>
File:        /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
Definition:  numpy.std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False)
Docstring:
Compute the standard deviation along the specified axis.

...

ddof : int, optional
    Means Delta Degrees of Freedom.  The divisor used in calculations
    is ``N - ddof``, where ``N`` represents the number of elements.
    By default `ddof` is zero.
```

Answer (score 2):

When getting into NumPy from Matlab, you'll probably want to keep the docs for both handy.  They're similar but often differ in small but important details.  Basically, they calculate the standard deviation differently.  I would strongly recommend checking the documentation for anything you use that calculates standard deviation, whether a pocket calculator or a programming language, since the default is not (sorry!) standardized.

Numpy STD: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Matlab STD: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html

The Numpy docs for `std` are a bit opaque, IMHO, especially considering that NumPy docs are generally fairly clear.  If you read far enough: `The average squared deviation is normally calculated as x.sum() / N, where N = len(x). If, however, ddof is specified, the divisor N - ddof is used instead. In standard statistical practice, ddof=1 provides an unbiased estimator of the variance of the infinite population.`  (In english, default is pop std dev, set `ddof=1` for sample std dev).

OTOH, the Matlab docs make clear the difference that's tripping you up:

`There are two common textbook definitions for the standard deviation s of a data vector X. [equations omitted]  n is the number of elements in the sample. The two forms of the equation differ only in n – 1 versus n in the divisor.`

So, by default, Matlab calculates the sample standard deviation (N-1 in the divisor, so bigger to compensate for the fact this is a sample) and Numpy calculates the population standard deviation (N in the divisor).  You use the `ddof` parameter to switch to the sample standard, or any other denominator you want (which goes beyond my statistics knowledge).

Lastly, it doesn't help on this problem, but you'll probably find this helpful at some point. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when would I ever need to use a value of `ddof` such that `ddof ∉ {0, 1}`?

Comment: I have no idea, I've only ever used those two.  Maybe a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/